# My first ruby app - fibonacci sequence

Tags: ruby

I am writing a method that returns the nth element in the Fibonacci sequence, but am running into an unexpected end error.

```
def fib_seq(n)

  a = [0]

  n.times do |i|
    if i==0
      a[i] = 0
    else if i==1
      a[i] = 1
    else
      a[i] = a[i-1] + a[i-2]
    end  
  end

  return a[n]
end

puts fib_seq(4)
```

Any tip on what I can be screwing up on?

Comment: Just an unrelated note: The naming convention for Ruby is to use `lowercase_with_underscores` for method and variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to return the nth (and not the (n-1)th, i.e. fib(1) = 0 NOT fib(0) = 0).

I fixed it by changing:

```
else if i==1
```

to

```
elsif i==1
```

(AND)

```
return a[n]
```

to

```
return a[n - 1]
```

So your final code should look like:

```
def fibSeq(n)

  a = [0]

  n.times do |i|
    if i==0
      a[i] = 0
    elsif i==1
      a[i] = 1
    else
      a[i] = a[i-1] + a[i-2]
    end  
  end

  return a[n-1]
end

puts fibSeq(4)
```

Per your comment below, the following code will work:

```
def fibSeq(n)

  a = [0]

  (n+1).times do |i|
    if i==0
      a[i] = 0
    elsif i==1
      a[i] = 1
    else
      a[i] = a[i-1] + a[i-2]
    end  
  end

  return a[n]
end

puts fibSeq(4)
```

If you want to output the fibs as a list then use:

```
return a[0..n]
```

Instead of

```
return a[n]
```

Comment: Which is the difference with else if and elsif in Ruby?  I'm sure you answer is correct.  I just want to know.

Comment: `elsif` is what a c-style programmer (let's just say that means C, C++, Java, C#, etc...) would know as `else if`. I believe that in ruby `else if` actually does two things it, (1) acts as the else from the above if statement, then it (2) acts as an if.

Comment: What if I want my sequence to be 0, 1, 1, 2, 3...?

Answer (score 2):

Very optimised code

Version 1

```
def fib(n, cache)
  return 1 if n <= 2
  return cache[n] if cache[n]
  cache[n] = fib(n - 1, cache) + fib(n - 2, cache)
end

cache = {}
puts fib(5,cache)
```

Version 2

```
def fib(n)
 return 1 if n <= 2
 fib_index = 3
 a, b = 1, 1
 while fib_index <= n
   c = a + b
   a = b
   b = c
   fib_index += 1
 end
c
end

puts fib(100)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you go recursive this is the seudo-code:

```
fib(n) {
    if n = 0 -> return 0
    else if n = 1 -> return 1
    else -> return fib(n-1) + fib (n-2)
}
```

Comment: Yeah recursive is good option but it will take good amount of time for n = 100